# Accessing Python module from different directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a project directory structure like below

```
|project 
 |-src 
  |- __init.py__
  |- features
   |- __init.py__
   |- clean_data.py
 |-notebooks 
  |- notebook.ipynb
```

The main directory is called project under which I have two directories- src and notebooks.

I want to import the module clean_data.py under features directory (which is under src) in my notebook.ipynb file.

If notebook.ipynb was directly one level up under project, I could have written

```
from src.features import clean_data
```

since all directories are serving as package with **init**.py file in each of them.

However my notebook.ipynb is under notebook directory under project. In that case how would you recommend accessing that module in this notebook?

Thanks

EDIT:

Actual dir structure image

[image]

Comment: Does `from ..src.features import clean_data` work?

Comment: got this error 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-0f6817688826> in <module>()
----> 1 from ..src.features import clean_data
      2 
   
      4 

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Can you put empty `__init__.py` file in each folder and try again?

Comment: its already there. The __init__.py is empty

Comment: You could try installing the project as a package so that the ipynb can access it as an installed package rather than having to use relative imports

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Its a python script file I wrote. I don't want to put it on pypi to install it later. 

I am not sure why it is not working. I have accessed files in same directoy via this method. That works. its just that this file is from diff directory that is causing issue.

I have again put empty __init__.py file in both main src folder and then in features folder. Its still same error

Comment: Here's the actual directory structure from my VSCode editor (attached in edit above). 

Same as above.

Comment: Have you placed one empty init file in project too?

Comment: no project folder doesn't have empty file as code modules are in src folder which is under project

Comment: Ok I added an empty init file in main project folder too. Still same error

Comment: You don't have to put it on pypi to make it installable, I don't know the specifics for VSCode, but if you add a setup.py in the project folder, you can use 
`pip install -e .` to make the project accessible without needing to work out the scope.

Comment: there is a setup.py in project folder. Are u saying just install pip install clean_data.py in same folder as project folder? My concern is without doing that it should also work with scope. Why isnt?

Comment: This article mentions the same thing we are doing. Why is it not working then? 

https://sweetcode.io/python-file-importation-multi-level-directory-modules-packages/

Comment: Can someone help pls? I am stuck here and I need to move with work. Thank You